# EXT Js Synchronous ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, function, extjs

How can I make synchronous ajax requests in EXT JS?

For example, given this code:

```
test1();
ajaxRequest(); //Ajax Request
test2();
```

The test2 function is executed without even finishing the execution of `ajaxRequest()`, which has an `Ext.Ajax.request` call .

How can I make `text2()` execute only after the `ajaxRequest()` function has been executed?

I understand that one way of doing it is to call the `test2` function in a callback, but I have some dependencies and a lot of code that has to be executed after the ajax request, in a synchronous manner.  Can you please help me with the best solution?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I needed something similar and after looking the source code of `Ext.Ajax.request()` and `Ext.data.Connection`, I found that they check for a `async` attribute, on the `request()` method, so, it's actually possible to make a synchronous request, like this:

```
var response = Ext.Ajax.request({
    async: false,
    url: 'service/url'
});
var items = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
```

It seems this `async` attribute is not documented, so... of course... be aware that it may change in future releases.

Comment: The async attribute is now documented for Ext.Ajax.request in the 5.0 release. See docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Ajax

Comment: for 3.4 I dont find async been used

Comment: This 100% works at least in version 4.2.

Answer (score 12):

In `Extjs.Ajax` each AJAX call results in one of three types of callback functions:

- `success` that runs if the AJAX call is successfully created and gets a response
- `failure` that runs if the AJAX call fails to get a response
- `callback` that runs AFTER the AJAX call gets a response

If you want to execute `test2();` after your ajax request finishes,
then put your `test2` function inside of a `success`, `failure`, or `callback` function; whichever one you choose is up to you...

More info on the `success` or `failure` function can be found [here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/api/Ext.Ajax.html).

```
test1();
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'page.php',
    params: {
        id: 1
    },
    // scope: this, // you can set the scope too
    callback: function(opt,success,respon){
        test2();
    } 
});
```

Note: This method doesn't work with ExtJS 3.

Answer (score 4):

ExtJS does not provide synchronous request capabilities out of the box.
In fact, they strongly discourage using them.

You may find the [following](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?7376-How-to-make-synchronous-AJAX-request-using-Ext-library&s=4106e43bf41451fb3db6b376799468f9) discussion helpful.

Comment: This is a 2007 discussion.

Comment: The async attribute is documented for Ext.Ajax.request in the 5.0 release. See http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Ajax