# How to wait till AJAX request will complete in ExtJS

Tags: ajax, extjs

I am calling AJAX request and getting the result as well but till that time next line of code start executing. I want to hold till AJAX success block executed.

PFB the code snippet.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: PORTALURL.EXCEPTION.MAX_VALUE,
    success: function(response) {
        var maxValue = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
        if (grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection().length > maxValue) {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Alert!', type + ' count is more than 10');
            return;
        }
    }
});

CommonUtil.alertConfirm(msg, function() {
.. }
```

In above code. Before AJAX request complete and alert box pop up comes, `alertConfirm` gets called.

Can anyone help in this.

Comment: What help? Directly add that statement inside the success block.

Comment: @HarshitShah The below alertConfirm is not rely on above AJAX request. That is different functionality.

Comment: So you are saying that sometimes you need to call that alert though success block is not executed and sometimes as you asked in question you want it to execute after success block execution?

Comment: @HarshitShah yes. my bad

Comment: Then atleast you are sure when will ajax request execute or it will always execute but if it goes to failure then you want the statement to execute and if it goes to success then execute it after success block?

Answer (score 2):

To wait until Ajax reponse, the best way is call that function from success block. So the code will be called after ajax response got it.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: PORTALURL.EXCEPTION.MAX_VALUE,
    success: function(response) {
        var maxValue = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
        if (grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection().length > maxValue) {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Alert!', type + ' count is more than 10');
            return;
        }

        // Call the required function which needs to be executed after ajax response.
        CommonUtil.alertConfirm(msg, function() {
        .. }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is such a property that allows for a request to become synchronous. By adding the property:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    async: true,
    // other properties for the request
});
```

More can be found in the Stackoverflow answer to a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14179683/9731205).